# How to configure two or more routers for home LAN + WiFi with exposed endpoints?

Tags: networking

I have a single IP address from my ISP.  I'm trying to expose two servers on my network to the internet, preferably behind a firewall, while also securing my home network from any exposure.  Additionally, I'd like to have a wireless router in a separate physical location in order to provide good coverage.

1. Does the following topology make sense from this perspective?
2. Does it make sense for the wireless router to create a separate subnet?
3. With this configuration will the WiFi clients be able to see the other LAN clients on 192.168.1.0/24?  What if this is desired?  What if it's not desired?

[image]

Thanks for any help/advice.  I feel like I know just enough about all of this to shoot myself in the foot!

Comment: 1) Do you actually **need** router 3 to be an actual router with its separate subnet, or do you only want a Wi-Fi radio? (Both make sense technically, the question is whether you need it practically.) 2) By "able to see", are you referring to LAN device _discovery_ like in Windows, or to direct TCP connections? (The latter obviously works fine across subnets; the former doesn't.)

Comment: 1) Good question.  Can you elaborate on WiFi radio?  Is that a consumer device that creates an AP on the same subnet?  I only have experience setting up actual WiFi routers.  2) Only direct TCP connections.

Comment: Yes, I meant an AP (access point; "range extender"). They're common in enterprises, with many dozens of APs providing access to the same subnet. (There's no routing involved in WiFi; they're just called "WiFi routers" because they happen to be a router + a WiFi AP all-in-one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Assign LAN segments based on purpose, not by "which router do they belong to".

2) You usually have (A) one segment behind a firewall for your servers, and (B) one segment for the devices in your home network (behind a second firewall), and possibly (C) one segment for guests.

3) LAN and WLAN can make a single segment (same IP range) if you bridge correctly. That's the simpler variant, but you can also use different segments and route, if you like - it's just more effort to set up.

4) All WLAN access points for a segment should have the same SSID. This means for "secondary" APs connected via LAN you'll have to bridge LAN and WLAN AP, which is not trivial on many off-the-shelf home routers unless you install OpenWRT etc. This is why many people end up with double NAT etc.

5) Think about where you want to have the DHCP server for each segment, where you want your DNS proxy, how you want to assign names for your devices, etc.

Comment: Re: (4) I'm currently running DD-WRT on my Linksys WRT1900ACS.  But it sounds like (3) is simpler.